# Headers for MSOffice 2007 / 97 Download with PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, http-headers

We're trying to send uploaded attachements (served from a database as blob) through php with Zend Framework to a client.

This code works fine for Excel97 / Word97.

```
  if ($this->getResponse()->canSendHeaders(false)) {
            $response = $this->getResponse();

            $response->setHeader('Pragma', 'public', true)
                     ->setHeader('Expires', '0', true)
                     ->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', true)
                     ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/force-download', true)
                     ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream', true)
                     ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/download', true)
                     ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', "attachment;filename=$filename", true)
                     ->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary', true)
                     ->setBody($data) // binary
                     ->sendHeaders();
        }
```

But is not working for excel2007 / word2007. It reports "file has an error" and trys to fix it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send the correct `Content-Type` for the given file format. That should be `application/msword`/`application/vnd.ms-excel` if you're sending old `.doc`- or `.xls`-files and `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` or `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for the newer `x`-type files `.docx` and `.xlsx` respectively (don't know which version you're serving).

Further more, as far as I know, the newer Office programs check if the file extension matches the file content, so you'll get errors or warnings when opening `.doc`-files with an `.docx`-extension.

A `...->setHeader('Content-Type', '<<the appropriate content-type>>', true)` should be sufficient.

Comment: You're sure that the file doesn't contain any invalid characters or that it isn't stored corrupt in the database?

Comment: when i put the binary data into an file it works, we ve now found out, that the download is one byte larger than the file..

Answer (score 0):

Different MIME types: http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php, at least that solved the problem for me when I had a similar one

Comment: still the same error wit "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"